# In-App-Purchase Bug

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm developing an iOS application in which users can buy an extra feature through an in app purchase. I have gotten the in app purchasing and restoring the purchases working correctly, where I save a `boolean` to the `NSUserDefaults` saying whether they have successfully bought and or restored the purchase.

However there is a bug where if User 1 buys the in app purchase on their phone, then logs into the App Store on User 2's phone and restores purchases. Then logs out again and allows User 2 to log back in, it means User 2 still has that in app purchase unlocked for free as the `boolean` in `NSUserDefaults` is still set to true.

I'm trying to find a way to query the user's App Store email or another way to check if the user's App Store email is the same as the one they bought the purchase under. But this needs to be done locally as the user could use this feature when they don't have any internet connection.

Does anyone have any suggestions of how I can do this or any better practices?

Thanks

Comment: This might rather qualify as an unforseen workaround regarding IAP rather than a bug, actually. Yet, catching this offline w/o access to apple's servers seems impossible, which is bad, imho.

Comment: You're right I just didn't know how to phrase it. It's annoying but I suppose it's an edge case that I assume other apps struggle with as well.

Comment: Right. Hence my favorite and upvote. Consider putting a bounty, as it didn't get much attention yet.

Comment: Even if you could check the email address signed into the store, that would be a bad idea because you can change the email address of an Apple ID.

Comment: Right, @DouglasHill, as detailed in my bounty, a answer might come up with any means to circumvent user behavior as stated in the question; probably by means of some unique, constant identifier.

Comment: OP, I did set a bounty. Feel free to self-answer a detailed 'cannot be done' in case the bounty runs out, you at least get something out of it :)

Answer (score 1):

This is, unfortunately by design, so as the old adage goes "it's not a bug, it's a feature".

It's designed like this so a user with multiple devices (e.g. iPhone and iPad), can make a purchase on the first device and benefit by restoring their purchases on their other device(s).

Of course this opens the door for people to share purchases across other peoples devices just as you describe.

The good news is there is a property on `SKPayment` called [`applicationUsername`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKMutablePaymentRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKMutablePayment/applicationUsername), its purpose as the docs state...

> Use this property to help the store detect irregular activity. For example, in a game, it would be unusual for dozens of different iTunes Store accounts to make purchases on behalf of the same in-game character.

If you don't have anything unique to identify the user, e.g. an email, username, id, etc then your problem can't be solved I'm sorry, but if you do, keep reading, this is where it gets interesting.

When the user restores their purchase you should use the [`restoreCompletedTransactionsWithApplicationUsername`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPaymentQueue/restoreCompletedTransactionsWithApplicationUsername:) method to make the call instead of `restoreCompletedTransactions`.

The docs are unclear what happens next, but my understanding is transaction state will be `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed` if the username sent in the purchase call is not the same as the username sent in the restore call.

But if i'm wrong then you should be able to find the `applicationUsername` on the [`payment`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransaction_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPaymentTransaction/payment) property of the transaction and compare it yourself before setting your property on `NSUserDefaults`. Sorry I haven't tried this myself, I only know the theory.

When setting the username, don't set it as plain text, the docs on [`applicationUsername`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKMutablePaymentRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKMutablePayment/applicationUsername) suggest that...

> The recommended implementation is to use a one-way hash of the user's account name to calculate the value for this property.

And further in [Detecting Irregular Activity](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/RequestPayment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH4-SW6) they explain...

> Don't use the Apple ID for your developer account, the user's Apple ID, or the user's unhashed account name on your server.

Also, ideally you will be using a constant identifier, i.e. something that can't be changed for the user. If you use a hash of their email address for instance, if they change it and you didn't keep that hash as a constant restoring will fail as an unintended side effect.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Keeping those hashes might not even suffice; in case of unrecoverable device loss, purchases should still be restorable. If the docs suggest not using the Apple ID, where do the docs think we'd get that from? If the API supplied that somewhere (which I doubt), we could hash that.

Comment: @SmokeDispenser my post assumes you have a unique identifier you can use like an ID from your own user database. But in most cases where an app is standalone nothing like this exists. Apple doesn't give you access to the users Apple ID for privacy reasons (and yeah I like how they include it in the docs if only to remind us of its tantalus existence). They offer the `identifierForVendor` but this is computed from the `bundleId` and the device, so you can't link it to a unique user. With Game Centre it might be possible to use the `playerId`.

Comment: `playerId` should not be used as several players may exists for one user. Also, `identifierForVendor` is not equal across devices or after fresh installs. This then leaves us with no option still then:/

Comment: @SmokeDispenser yup, the pursuit is futile, sorry.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all the help, unfortunately we took In-App Purchases out of the app in the end (nothing to do with the question I posted), so I haven't been able to put these ideas to the test.

Answer (score 0):

You can control it via your servers by checking originalTransactionIdentifier of the receipts. As this remains same for all the purchased from one itunes account. You can associate this originalTransactionIdentifier with the username. Next time if you receive some already stored originalTransactionIdentifier against a different username, you can take the actions according to your suitability.